# What is profiling in unix?

Tags: unix

Can anybody tell me about 'profiling' in unix by giving a small example.
                                                                      Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: Profiling in unix is the same thing it is on other platforms: peaking into the program execution to see where it spends it's time. Lots of questions about the tool available on unix around already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiling or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux+profiling if you mean Linux in particular.

Comment: @Ether: No its not any homework but from next week I'm going to have exam so preparing.... :)

Comment: what does your textbook say about this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give us some more context if you want a useful answer. Broadly speaking, profiling a program is to instrument the executable with some extra statements that record details of execution which you can later analyse to identify parts that are slow, consume too much memory, consume too much CPU etc. Here's a quickie along with examples on how to use `gprof` which is the GNU profiler for C. http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shine in your exam about profiling, talk about [Dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).